# How to prevent scroll event from the bottom of the screen on iOS Safari

Tags: javascript, scroll, mobile-safari

There is a scroll event happening with unknown source when using iOS safari.

To reproduce the issue
You can use this link to explore a minimal example of the issue.

https://codesandbox.io/s/frosty-pike-7z6v9?file=/src/styles.css&resolutionWidth=444&resolutionHeight=649

Using an iphone, try to scroll until you get rid of safari bottom nav bar, then scroll in the non scrolling red area at the very bottom edge of the screen.

- What's causing that behaviour (event name) ?
- Can scrolling be prevented using this method with Javascript without
  extra css ?

*Update 1* : While there is no known method to solve this as it seems, force showing the bottom all the time did work for my specific use case.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can scrolling be prevented using this method with Javascript without extra css?

**I fear the answer is simply no. :(**

---

Here's the most meaningful source I could find: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=189586 (~2.5 years ago)

In this source, refer to the section "Level 6: iOS Safari restricted browser area": https://medium.com/turo-engineering/ios-mobile-scroll-in-web-react-1d92d910604b

Another: https://benfrain.com/the-ios-safari-menu-bar-is-hostile-to-web-apps-discuss/

References made in issues from the `body-scroll-lock` library:

- https://github.com/willmcpo/body-scroll-lock/issues/211#issuecomment-761564904
- https://github.com/willmcpo/body-scroll-lock/issues/82 (where I found the webkit bug)
- More generally, just searching open issues with "scroll" adds a lot of supplemental information that all seems to arrive back at the answer of no, sadly preventing scroll does not work in iOS Safari when the menu bar is hidden.

Comment: thanks for your answer.
Although I don't have a solution to the bug, referring to the medium article gave me really good insight of what's happening.
I will update the question if I found a work around or anything shows up.

Answer (score 0):

Safari on iOS has a so-called overscoll/bounce effect. You can eliminate the effect by using `position:fixed` on the body. Disadvantage is that the bottom navbar appears again, but at least the following code prevents scrolling of the red area.

In your css, set the width of the body:

```
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  width:100vw;
}
```

Then in you javascript, add `position:fixed` on `touchstart`, remove it on `touchend`, like so:

```
document
.getElementById("noScrollArea")
.addEventListener("touchstart", (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()

    var height = document.body.clientHeight;
    document.body.style.height = height + 'px';
    document.body.style.position = 'fixed';
});
document
.getElementById("noScrollArea")
.addEventListener("touchend", (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    document.body.style.height = 'initial';
    document.body.style.position = 'initial';
});
```

I hope this helps you in the right direction...

Comment: Sorry I sadly can't accept your solution.
1. It doesn't work, safari doesn't give you the ability to detect these events at the same area.
2. I don't want to add any extra css outside of the component that's the whole point of my question, this will create a component with a side effect, it's really bad to have something like that.

Comment: What do you mean by 'safari doesn't give you the ability to detect these events at the same area'. Here is a working demo: https://klaasmaakt.nl/test. Your problem with the overscroll effect can only be overcome by adding `fixed` to the body, as far as I know, so that's the only option if you ask me....

Comment: Hey please check @mcy answer